# linking rows of mySQL database to the referred page

Tags: php, mysql

I am having difficulty in linking each row of my database to display the link which will show another mySQL database table. I think the error comes from the second part of my code not the first where my query might not be right but i cant figure out which part I need to change.
these are my codes so far:

```
                              </tr>  
                      </thead>  
                      <?php  
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                      {  

                    $id = $row['my30_rsl_id'];
                     $SupplierName = $row['SupplierName'];
                     $Commodity = $row['Commodity'];

echo '

                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$row["my30_rsl_id"].'</td> 
                                <td><a href="request.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $SupplierName . '</a></td>
                                <td><a href="request.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $Commodity . '</a></td>
                                <td>'.$row["Sub-Category"].'</td>    
                                <td>'.$row["Status"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["Location"].'</td>  

                           </tr>  
                           ';  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>
```

the page where the link refers to :
(it returns error at $result)

```
 <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM my30_rsl WHERE my30_rsl_id = $id");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Details</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container">  
            <h3 align="center">Details</h3>  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table id="supplier_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                      <thead>  
                           <tr>

                                <td>SupplierName</td>   
                                <td>Comments</td>


                           </tr>  
                      </thead>  
                      <?php  
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                      {  
                    echo '
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href=#>'.$row["SupplierName"] . '</a> </td> 
                                <td>'.$row["Comments"].'</td>    

                           </tr>  
                           ';  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  


         </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  


    <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
          $('#supplier_data').DataTable();  
     });  
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably some naming issues? Your code with comment

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM my30_rsl WHERE my30_rsl_id = $id");
                   //  ^--- where does that come from? you only have $connect
```

so you probably have to name it `$connect`. If that's not the problem, maybe you should look at the error messages, use search engines for that error message and find out what's wrong.

Also, your code is vulnerable to sql injections. Learn how to use prepared statements, please.

Comment: thx very much for correcting my stupid mistake and i will change my code. =)